# How to maintain dynamic className elegantly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Everything work as expected for the UI rendering. As project grows, more UI condition kicks in for different scenario and we start playing with Tenary Operator to decide how the UI looks like.

**Problem statement:**
It become uglier as it grows, tough to read and maintain by one.

**Sample code**

```
const renderBtn = () => {   
    return null;

    if(validCondition){
        return(
            <div>
              <SomeComponent
                className="outlineBtn someClassName"
                children={<div className="textBtn">Add Gas</div>}
                size="medium"
                onClick={() => performAction()}
              />
              <SomeComponent
                className={`inlineBtn someClassName 
                ${amount != 0 ? "disableBtn" : null}`
                }
                children={<div className="textBtn">Settle</div>}
                size="medium"
              />
            <div>
        )
    }
}



return(
    <div>
        <div>
            ...something else
        </div>
        {renderView1()}
        {renderView2()}
        {renderBtn()}
    </div>
)
```

Only way I can think to **improve readability** is by moving out the render condition into a method. This could provide a better reading but the `className` still "an issue" to me.

How can I handle this more elegantly?

Comment: Note your current attempt is including the literal class name `null` in some cases, which you probably don't want. Look into libraries like classnames and clsx which offer alternatives for dynamically building these strings.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames might help

Comment: The canonical evergreen library for this is [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames).

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the sharp catch, this is just part of the sample code. There are cases where different className does applied. Appreciate if you could point a better way out.

Comment: I've pointed out two...

Comment: yup, my bad sry.

Answer (score 1):

Using e.g. the [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) library, one way to do this would be

```
import cx from 'classnames';

<SomeComponent
  className={cx({
    inlineBtn: true,
    someClassName: true,
    disableBtn: amount != 0,
  })}
  children={<div className="textBtn">Settle</div>}
  size="medium"
/>
```

or

```
className={cx("inlineBtn someClassName", {disableBtn: amount != 0})}
```

Comment: hi @AKX. thanks for the suggestion, but I don't get the idea behind, how is this different or better than what my sample code is showing? To me it looks the same with conditional inside, and potentially with more lines of code since everything is going to refer from your boolean value.

Comment: @TommyLeong with `classnames` you can separate the default classes from the conditional ones. If you component is handling too many cases, perhaps it's trying to do too much and should be split between different components. You can always write your `getClasses(...)` function and write all the logic there.

Comment: Well, as @jonrsharpe pointed out, your current code has the bug that your classname will end up being `inlineBtn someClassName null` – that won't happen with this. You could also use object splatting to split the object you pass to  `cx`: `cx({...getSomeClasses(props), ...getOtherClasses(props), hello: true})`

Comment: @AKX agree. Based on your suggestions, if I have 2 conditions that link with 4 different classes, I will end up to maintain with 2 extra variable like `isInline` `canProceed`.  Something like this I guess? ```className={cx({
    inlineBtn: isInline,
    outline: isInline,
    enableBtn: canProceed
    disableBtn: canProeced
})}```

Comment: @TommyLeong More simply put with computed keys: `cx({[inlineBtn ? 'isInline' : 'isOutline']: true, [canProceed ? 'enableBtn' : 'disableBtn']: true})`

Comment: Thanks @AKX. Just trying to undersatnd, but how is this better than tenary operator? I see no difference too, almost as lengthy as current.